# Running Ember's todos example

Tags: ember.js

I'm a RoR newbie, trying to run the todos example using the [readme](https://github.com/emberjs/todos/blob/master/README.md).
Running bundle works fine:

```
$ bundle
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using chunky_png (1.2.5) 
Using fssm (0.2.8.1) 
Using sass (3.1.15) 
Using compass (0.11.7) 
Using json (1.6.5) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using rake-pipeline (0.6.0) from https://github.com/livingsocial/rake-pipeline.git (at master) 
Using rake-pipeline-web-filters (0.6.0) from https://github.com/wycats/rake-pipeline-web-filters.git (at master) 
Using bundler (1.0.22) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Running

> bundle exec rakep server
>   does not work for me:

```
$ bundle exec rakep server
/Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-web-filters-e58b9d055de6/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters/version.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant VERSION
/Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-web-filters-e58b9d055de6/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters.rb:23:in `require': /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-web-filters-e58b9d055de6/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters/chained_filter.rb:45: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=\.)\w+/ (SyntaxError)
    from /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-web-filters-e58b9d055de6/lib/rake-pipeline-web-filters.rb:23
    from /Users/<my_user>/projects/todos/Assetfile:3:in `require'
    from /Users/<my_user>/projects/todos/Assetfile:3:in `rebuild_from_assetfile'
    from /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-f71caeb1406d/lib/rake-pipeline/dsl/project_dsl.rb:25:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-f71caeb1406d/lib/rake-pipeline/dsl/project_dsl.rb:25:in `evaluate'
    from /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-f71caeb1406d/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb:92:in `build'
    from /Users/<my_user>/projects/todos/Assetfile:1:in `rebuild_from_assetfile'
    from /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-f71caeb1406d/lib/rake-pipeline/project.rb:83:in `initialize'
    from /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-f71caeb1406d/lib/rake-pipeline/middleware.rb:24:in `new'
    from /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-f71caeb1406d/lib/rake-pipeline/middleware.rb:24:in `initialize'
    from /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-f71caeb1406d/lib/rake-pipeline/server.rb:11:in `new'
    from /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-f71caeb1406d/lib/rake-pipeline/server.rb:11:in `app'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-f71caeb1406d/lib/rake-pipeline/cli.rb:38:in `server'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
    from /Users/<my_user>/.bundler/ruby/1.8/rake-pipeline-f71caeb1406d/bin/rakep:4
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bin/rakep:19:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/bin/rakep:19
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, Rake Pipeline only runs under Ruby 1.9. This is probably fixable and should be considered a bug in Rake Pipeline. I'd recommend using Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM anyway.